# AngularJS, how to generate routing rules dynamically from web service which returns json?

Tags: angularjs, json, ngroute

I want to generate routing rules dynamically, based on a web service which returns a JSON file.
Is this possible?
I am working with Angular 1.4.7.

Comment: Can you give an example of the JSON you'd receive and how you'd like to use it?

Comment: Maybe you don't need that. Maybe you need only the base url ?
As @HarrisWeinstein said, can you provide us an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a cool way to do it,
the solution is to write a global variable then update the content.
Here is an example:

```js
//global variable
var $routeProviderReference;
//global variable

var app=angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize']);
app.config(function($mdThemingProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  
//link global variable to router Provider reference      
 $routeProviderReference = $routeProvider;
//link global variable to router Provider reference 
  
});

app.run(function($templateCache, $rootScope, $http, $route, dataFactory) {
 
  //get routing rules from web service
  $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'webservice-URL' }).then(function (e){
 //set routing rules in global variable
     $routeProviderReference.when('/'+e.data.page, {
                  templateUrl: 'static/tpl/default.html',
                  controller: function($scope) {
                      $scope.data=e.data.feed.entry; 
                  }
                });
  }, function (err){
     console.log(err);
  );
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
```